# Why are my console.log statements not showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, cgi

I have a Bible search and passage lookup tool at http://jonathanhayward.com/powerbible.cgi. This tool is relatively mature, has seen much productive use, but it has a bit of an [EMERAC metaphor](http://www.ronaldbieber.de/Interface_Hall_of_Shame/metaphors.html#METAPHOR8) for searching: it presents too many options at first, showing things that should be deferred to progressive disclosure if the user wants a more specific search.

At present the left pane has the [EMERAC syndrome](http://www.ronaldbieber.de/Interface_Hall_of_Shame/metaphors.html#METAPHOR8); it presents numerous options. And all of the "don't show unless asked" options are in containers that have the CSS class "advanced_search", but an attempt to call simple_or_advanced_search() seems to result in a call to the function, with the parameter in a console.log() if I do a console.log(), but without seeming to hide the tr's that have the class 'advanced_search'. The function is, without adorning an old Tcl multiline string:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
     <!--
     function simple_or_advanced_search(advanced_value)
     {
     if (advanced_value == "advanced")
     {
     jQuery('.advanced_search').show();
     jQuery('.advanced_search_alternate').hide();
     }
     else
            {
     jQuery('.advanced_search').hide();
     jQuery('.advanced_search_alternate').show();
     }
     document.bibletool.advancedSearch.value = advanced_value;
     }
     // -->
     </script>
```

The debugging output shows this is being called with an argument of "simple", as intended, but so far I haven't seen any portion of the input hidden/shown. Chrome and Firebug do not report errors.

The source is at http://jonathanhayward.com/powerbible.txt.

Comment: Where in your code are there `console.log` function calls? Also you're question seemed quite confusing to me. Can you boil your question down to exactly what you think is wrong and what you think needs to be fixed?

Comment: I'm with @Jasper in the collective "huh?"

Comment: @JonathanHayward I don't see any console.log statements either in the posted code (which is commented out, by the way) or in the linked powerbible.txt file.

Comment: I took out the console.log() statements before posting. I want table rows with class 'advanced_search' to be displayed with progressive disclosure, i.e. not unless the user clicks the 'Advanced Search' link. However, those table rows are not hidden even when I specify advanced_search to be display: none in the initial CSS.